# Windows firewall rules keep reverting after refresh

Tags: firewall, refresh

When i create a new firewall role (inbound or outbound) in the `Windows Firewall and Advanced Security` after refresh, it disappears! I have this problem recently and i don't know why? (I searched and there is no specific local group policy that may cause that.) My OS: Windows 8.1

[image]
I reset firewall settings to default but it keeps resetting to it's default settings ... It's like the `Netsh advfirewall firewall reset` command is running always!!!

Comment: What do you mean by "refresh"?

Comment: @DavidPostill The refresh in the right-click menu context of firewall snap-in Or even when you close and reopen the firewall settings.

Comment: This behavior is to be expected.  When you initiated a "Refresh" action in Windows 10, Windows 10 is reinstalled on the HDD
, then your user files are moved to the new installation.

Comment: @Ramhound No i didn't do anything to my Win8.1 .... few weeks ago i create some firewall rules and they were working fine until recently i noticed that those rules aren't there anymore and worse i can't create rule because it disappears after creation.

Comment: You mention in your question you used the refresh option within `Windows 8.1`, disregard the pat of the comment about Windows 10, should have recognized you were using Windows 8.1 not Windows 10.

Comment: see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd364373(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Is this computer attached to a domain?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 No It's not joined to a domain

Comment: It's like the `NETSH` command causes this problem but i don't know how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just stumbled upon the same or very similar problem in Win 10:

1. Open "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security"
2. Right click "Inbound Rules", "New rule..."
3. Setup the rule with whatever settings and save it
4. At this point I can confirm rule is working
5. Few seconds later rule stops working. If I refresh "Inbound Rules" my rule is disappeared.

I have restarted windows, tried SFC scan, "netsh firewall reset", scanned with anti-malware software, inspected running processes, but nothing helped.

Then I started stopping services and after I stopped "TunnelBear Maintenance" service the problem was solved and my custom rules have been persistently saved. This service belongs to TunnelBear VPN app.

Check for TunnelBear. If you don't have it, I suggest to start stopping non-windows services and keep adding and watching if rule is disappearing after each stopped service.

Comment: An amazing catch sir!  Well done.  This is exactly my situation and I honestly doubt I would ever have found it.  I needed to stop the service AND the TunnelBear GUI program to stop my rules vanishing.

Comment: I have reported this to TunnelBear support.

Comment: Yes ... i have "TunnelBear" VPN and you are right .... that's problem .... thanks

Comment: Thanks for the catch, I spent 3 hrs pulling my hair off. Disabling "TunnelBear Maintenance" service fixed it